# Couchbase: Could not dispatch request, cancelling instead of retrying

Tags: java, couchbase

In the case of running queries asynchronously, client crash with the error:

```
com.couchbase.client.core.RequestCancelledException: Could not dispatch request, canceling instead of retrying.
```

Connection Settings:

```
final CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment
  .builder()
  .queryEndpoints(1)
  .retryStrategy(FailFastRetryStrategy.INSTANCE)
  .build();
```

Async query example:

```
Observable<SiteData> dataList = bucket
  .async()
  .query(query)
  .flatMap(AsyncN1qlQueryResult::rows)
  .map(row -> new SiteData(row.value()));
```

Answer (score 0):

The reason is `queryEndpoints` set to 1 and strategy to `FailFastRetryStrategy`, so, running two requests asynchronously, will fail because there is only one endpoint and strategy is to fail in the case of any exception.

Rise the `queryEndpoints` or change strategy to `BestEffortRetryStrategy` or do both:

```
final CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment
  .builder()
  .queryEndpoints(2)
  .retryStrategy(BestEffortRetryStrategy.INSTANCE)
  .build();
```