# Create or update a full text search in couchbase with java client

Tags: java, couchbase

I am trying to create a full text search in couchbase using java client `UpsertSearchIndexRequest` as mentioned in the doucmentation [here](https://forums.couchbase.com/t/how-to-create-fts-index-from-couchbase-java-sdk/18159). However, I'm getting a `RequestCancelledException`.

```
String payload = null;
    try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(resource.getInputStream()),1024);
            StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();
            String line;
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                stringBuilder.append(line).append('\n');
            }
            br.close();
            payload = stringBuilder.toString();
     } catch (Exception e) {
            System.out.println(e);
     }
     CouchbaseEnvironment env = DefaultCouchbaseEnvironment.builder()
             .connectTimeout(60000)
             .retryStrategy(BestEffortRetryStrategy.INSTANCE)
             .queryServiceConfig(QueryServiceConfig.create(2,50))
             .mutationTokensEnabled(true)
             .computationPoolSize(5)
             .build();
    CouchbaseCluster couchbaseCluster = CouchbaseCluster.create(env, "127.0.0.1");

    CouchbaseResponse response = couchbaseCluster.core()
            .send(new UpsertSearchIndexRequest("demoIndex", payload, "null", "password"))
            .toBlocking()
            .single();
    System.out.println(response.status().isSuccess());
```

**Current result:**

> Getting the foloowing exception Caused by:
>   com.couchbase.client.core.RequestCancelledException: Could not
>   dispatch request, cancelling instead of retrying.     at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.retry.RetryHelper.retryOrCancel(RetryHelper.java:51)
>   ~[core-io-1.7.2.jar:na]   at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.node.locate.QueryLocator.locateAndDispatch(QueryLocator.java:80)
>   ~[core-io-1.7.2.jar:na]   at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.dispatchRequest(RequestHandler.java:259)
>   ~[core-io-1.7.2.jar:na]   at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.onEvent(RequestHandler.java:208)
>   ~[core-io-1.7.2.jar:na]   at
>   com.couchbase.client.core.RequestHandler.onEvent(RequestHandler.java:79)
>   ~[core-io-1.7.2.jar:na]   at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.com.lmax.disruptor.BatchEventProcessor.run(BatchEventProcessor.java:150)
>   ~[core-io-1.7.2.jar:na]   at
>   com.couchbase.client.deps.io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
>   ~[core-io-1.7.2.jar:na]   at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:748)
>   ~[na:1.8.0_131]

**Expected result:**

> Create/update index in couchbase.

Comment: Possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43123836/couchbase-could-not-dispatch-request-cancelling-instead-of-retrying?